# Data copy problem in windows

Tags: windows-explorer

I have some data in my one of the folder.
I am Just copy To other Place even in Pendrive but in that Messege showing cyclick redundanc check.I know its probrolm when data is not reachable or found.still I want to Transfer the data.

Comment: Is that an error? If so, can you copy the exact error here? (Click inside the window, press CTRL+C and then edit your question and CTRL+V at the end.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRC errors usually mean that something is wrong with the drive, most likely from pulling it out too early.

You should try running chkdsk. Here's a good guide that works for Win 7 and XP: http://www.w7forums.com/use-chkdsk-check-disk-t448.html